# :last-child and :last-of-type not working as intended

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of my code:

```css
.item:not(:last-child) {
   margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <span class="error-messages"></span>
   <span class="help-block"></span>
</fieldset>
```

In my mind, the expected behavior of this is to select every element *besides* the last element with the `.item` class name. However, it's not doing that unless I delete the two `span` elements at the bottom of `fieldset`.

When I place the above CSS selector into Chrome's Developer Tools, it selects the last-child as intended but doesn't actually do anything - it's greyed out for some reason.

Can anyone assist me with a solution for selecting all but the last `.item` element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `last-of-type` instead of `last-child`:

```css
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
   margin-bottom: 12px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #999; /*Just to make sure*/
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <div class="item">1</div>
   <div class="item">2</div>
   <div class="item">3</div>
   <div class="item">4</div>
   <div class="item">5</div>
   <!-- Just to make sure -->
   <span class="error-messages">Error Messages Here</span>
   <span class="help-block">Help Block Here</span>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage of `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child` will resolve your problem. This happens when you wrap elements of other types inside the same parent. In the case of `:last-child` compiler checks until the end of the file if there's any other element with class `.item`. So according to the TopDown approach, the code doesn't work as expected. `:last-child` should maximum be used with elemental styling. Like `li:last-child`

So Try this:

```css
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
   margin-bottom: 12px;
   border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
       <div class="item">1</div>
       <div class="item">2</div>
       <div class="item">3</div>
       <div class="item">4</div>
       <div class="item">5</div>
       <span class="error-messages">It works as expected</span>
       <span class="help-block">Now</span>
</fieldset>
```